# metro-bootstrap.css - Unable to align 'nav' to center of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the 'metro-bootstrap.css' (http://talkslab.github.io/metro-bootstrap/) but I am unable to align my Nav list and need some help, spent the past few days tediously going over and over this but nothing will align it!. You can get a better idea of this on my site advinadv.co.uk .. Hope someone can help!

here is my HTML;

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
                <br /><h1>advinadv.co.uk</h1>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#sectionID2">About Us</a> </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#sectionID3">Services</a> </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#sectionID4">Portfolio</a> </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to share showing what you have tried? A JSFiddle would be a great start.

Comment: How do you want to align the Nav list?

Comment: I have added my html above, the .css I can provide, but there is pages and I am unable to locate the exact section that requires amending. http://advinadv.co.uk/css/metro-bootstrap.css - this is the best way of me providing this, I don't expect anyone to go through it all.. I have tried several things such as { width:100%; text-align:center; dislay:block; position:fixed; } but no matter what I put or where, this makes no difference (I have only been adding this to any 'nav' '.nav'

Comment: @Skelly I just want the 'home/about us/services..' to fit under the header, just needs to go slightly to the right

Comment: So you want it centered?

Comment: Sorry yes, centred to match that of the header (just realised I just put align and didn't specify how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in your css , it will change your nav to center

```
.nav-collapse.collapse 
{
height: auto !important;
overflow: visible !important;
text-align: center;
}
.navbar .nav {
 display: inline-block;
 float: none;
 left: 0; 
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @prerit ! Show's in the Center now, can see on my site.. finally! I don't suppose you have any suggestions for the height, ideally want the Nav links to sit about 15px above the bottom of the Navbar and the only way I can seem to get around the Title touching the very top of the page is to add a <br /> before <h1>advinadv.co.uk</h1>.. or wrap this in a </div id="pagtitle"> which I have done on my live site and added .pagetitle {margin-top:15px;) to the CSS

Comment: Thanks, i looked in to your site. its looking good. You can always use padding or margin to adjust your layout. it is not good practice to use </br> for layout purpose.

Comment: Thank you, amended a few more bits now, managed to remove all the <br />'s